# What the best way to execute "not transformation" actions in elements of a Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Newly coming in spark, I'm looking for a way to execute actions in all elements of a Dataset with Spark **structured streaming**:

I know this is a specific purpose case, what I want is iterate through all elements of Dataset, do an action on it, then continue to work with Dataset.

Example:

I got `val df = Dataset[Person]`, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
def execute(df: Dataset[Person]): Dataset[Person] = {
 df.foreach((p: Person) => {
   someHttpClient.doRequest(httpPostRequest(p.asString)) // this is pseudo code / not compiling
 })
 df
}
```

Unfortunately, `foreach` is not available with structured streaming since I got error **"Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start"**

I tried to use `map()`, but then error **"Task not serializable"** occured, I think because http request, or http client, is not serializable.

I know Spark is mostly use for filter and transform, but is there a way to handle well this specific use case ?

Thanks :)

Comment: afaik foreach is available when foreachbatch cannot be used in Sp St St

Answer (score 2):

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(“local[*]").setAppName(“Example")
val jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(1)) // second option tell about The time interval at which streaming data will be divided into batches
```

Before concluding on whether a solution exists or not
Let’s as few questions

How does Spark Streaming work?
Spark Streaming receives live input data streams from input source and divides the data into batches, which are then processed by the Spark engine and final batch results are pushed down to downstream applications

How Does the batch execution start?
Spark does lazy evaluations on all the transformation applied on Dstream.it will apply transformation on **actions** (i.e only when you start streaming context)

```
   jssc.start();              // Start the computation
   jssc.awaitTermination();   // Wait for the computation to terminate.
```

Note : Each Batch of Dstream contains multiple partitions ( it is just like running sequence of spark-batch job until input source stop producing data)

So you can have custom logic like below.

```
dStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction[JavaRDD[Object]] {
  override def call(t: JavaRDD[Object]): Unit = {
    t.foreach(new VoidFunction[Object] {
      override def call(t: Object): Unit = {
        //pseudo code someHttpClient.doRequest(httpPostRequest(t.asString))
      }
    })
  }
})
```

But again make sure your someHttpClient is serializable **or**

you can create that object As mentioned below.

```
dStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction[JavaRDD[Object]] {
      override def call(t: JavaRDD[Object]): Unit = {
        // create someHttpClient object
        t.foreach(new VoidFunction[Object] {
          override def call(t: Object): Unit = {
            //pseudo code someHttpClient.doRequest(httpPostRequest(t.asString))
          }
        })
      }
    })
```

**Related to Spark Structured Streaming**

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql._;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("example")
  .getOrCreate();

val lines = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 9999).load(); // this is example source load copied from spark-streaming doc

lines.foreach(new ForeachFunction[Row] {
  override def call(t: Row): Unit = {
    //someHttpClient.doRequest(httpPostRequest(p.asString))
       OR
    // create someHttpClient object here and use it to tackle serialization errors
  }
})

// Start running the query foreach and do mention downstream sink below/
val query = lines.writeStream.start
query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Related to Structured Streaming part doesn't works on my side. I got "Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start" message. That's why I said foreach is not compliant with structured streaming

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreach   That comment is not correct

Comment: we're not about the same `foreach` method. I'm about the one on the Dataset, not the DataStreamWriter ...